# Finding the Inverse Laplace Transform of $-\frac{1}{s(s+1)}+\frac{(s+1)(s+2)}{s\left((s+1)^2+1\right)}$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, laplace-transform

> I am trying to find the inverse Laplace transform of $$F(s)=-\frac{1}{s(s+1)}+\frac{(s+1)(s+2)}{s\left((s+1)^2+1\right)}.$$

I proceeded as follows:

\begin{align}
F(s)&=-\frac{1}{s(s+1)}+\frac{(s+1)(s+2)}{s\left((s+1)^2+1\right)} \\
&=-\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{s+1}+\frac{s+1}{(s+1)^2+1}+\frac{4}{s\left((s+1)^2+1\right)} \\
f(t)&=-1+e^{-t}+e^{-t}\cos(t)+\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{s}\times\frac{1}{(s+1)^2+1}\right) \\
&=-1+e^{-t}+e^{-t}\cos(t)+4\int_0^{\infty}e^{-u}\sin(u) \ du \ \ \ \ \ \text{(convolution theorem)} \\
&=1+e^{-t}(1+\cos(t))
\end{align}
But the answer is apparently $f(t)=e^{-t}(1+\sin(t)).$ I have looked over my worked and agree with my solution.

edit:

\begin{align}
\frac{(s+1)(s+2)}{s\left((s+1)^2+1\right)}&=\frac{s^2+3s+2}{s\left((s+1)^2+1\right)} \\
&=\frac{s^2+3s}{s\left((s+1)^2+1\right)}+\frac{2}{s\left((s+1)^2+1\right)} \\
&=\frac{s(s+3)}{s\left((s+1)^2+1\right)}+\frac{2}{s\left((s+1)^2+1\right)} \\
&=\frac{s+3}{(s+1)^2+1}+\frac{2}{s\left((s+1)^2+1\right)} \\
&=\frac{s+1}{(s+1)^2+1}+\frac{4}{s\left((s+1)^2+1\right)}
\end{align}

Comment: In the partial fractions, if you add the partial fractions of the second term, it doesn't yield the original one. I think there's some mistake in it.

Comment: I think the calculation in the $2^{nd}$ line (expression of $F(s)$) is wrong. Please check.

Comment: @nmasanta of the first of second term from the first line? I have checked

Comment: see the expression given by Geethu Joseph in the answer section. @Stuart-James Burney.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your partial fractions are not correct for the second term:
\begin{equation}
\frac{(s+1)(s+2)}{s((s+1)^2+1)}=\frac{1}{(s+1)^2+1}+\frac{1}{s}.
\end{equation}
Then,
\begin{equation}
F(s) = \frac{1}{(s+1)}+\frac{1}{(s+1)^2+1}.
\end{equation}
Thus, you get the desired result!

Comment: Thanks, but I still can't see my error. I've uploaded an edit. Are you able to point out where I am incorrect?

Comment: The error is in the last step: $\frac{s+3}{(s+1)^2+1}+\frac{2}{s((s+1)^2+1)} = \frac{s+1}{(s+1)^2+1}+\frac{2}{(s+1)^2+1}+\frac{2}{s((s+1)^2+1)}=\frac{s+1}{(s+1)^2+1}+\frac{2s+2}{s((s+1)^2+1)}$.

Comment: Yep, you're absolutely correct. Ignore my sleep deprived brain

Comment: Quick question: Is it not also possible to take the inverse Laplace transform of $$\frac{s+1}{(s+1)^2+1}+\frac{2}{(s+1)^2+1}+\frac{2}{s((s+1)^2+1)} \tag{1}$$ and not $$\frac{s+1}{(s+1)^2+1}+\frac{2s+2}{s((s+1)^2+1)}?$$ The inverse Laplace transform of $(1)$ is $$e^{-t}+e^{-t}\cos(t)+2e^{-t}\sin(t).$$

Comment: Note that the Laplace transform of (1) is \begin{equation}e^{-t}\cos t+2e^{-t}\sin t +2 \int_0^te^{-\tau}\sin\tau d\tau=e^{-t}\cos t+2e^{-t}\sin t -e^{-t}\cos t+1-e^{-t}\sin t=e^{-t}\sin t +1\end{equation}